# Discord.gateway warning "Shard ID None heartbeat blocked for more than 10 seconds."

Tags: python, discord

I don't understand python and discrod bots. This code was written for me, a person who can no longer maintain contact with anyone at all.
The error itself:

```
Loop thread traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\.HgBots\HG_bot_roles-main/main.py", line 877, in <module>
    client.run(discord_token)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 860, in run
    asyncio.run(runner())
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 190, in run
    return runner.run(main)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 118, in run
    return self._loop.run_until_complete(task)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 640, in run_until_complete
    self.run_forever()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\asyncio\windows_events.py", line 321, in run_forever
    super().run_forever()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 607, in run_forever
    self._run_once()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1922, in _run_once
    handle._run()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\asyncio\events.py", line 80, in _run
    self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
  File "C:\.HgBots\HG_bot_roles-main/main.py", line 585, in update_roles
    users_list = addRoles(parsTimeAllUsers())
  File "C:\.HgBots\HG_bot_roles-main/main.py", line 284, in parsTimeAllUsers
    all = getAllTimeAndTimeSplitDay().copy()
  File "C:\.HgBots\HG_bot_roles-main/main.py", line 306, in getAllTimeAndTimeSplitDay
    users = copy.deepcopy(getDailyOnTime(f"/plugins/OnTime/{date} DailyReport.txt"))
  File "C:\.HgBots\HG_bot_roles-main/main.py", line 357, in getDailyOnTime
    table = treadingWaiting(8, getSFTPfile, patch)
  File "C:\.HgBots\HG_bot_roles-main/main.py", line 246, in treadingWaiting
    t.join(time_sleep)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\threading.py", line 1123, in join
    self._wait_for_tstate_lock(timeout=max(timeout, 0))
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\threading.py", line 1139, in _wait_for_tstate_lock
    if lock.acquire(block, timeout):
```

The code itself, I can remove part of it when clearing tokens and links to my SFTP:

https://pastebin.com/2pczxXJt

I tried to contact ChatGPT, each time it gave a different problem, either a problem with threads or with optimization.
I can assume that Discord has just updated the requirements for asynchronous tasks for bots, I am not capable and do not know how to solve the problem on my own, so I am asking for help, sorry.
After referring to similar posts, I don’t understand what to do and how to apply the instructions from them, sorry

Comment: where is the code that produced this error ?  the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)